# SharePoint 2013 hosted add-in App URL

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I am working on SharePoint 2013 OnPremise test environment.
I've created a SharePoint-Hosted Add-In and its url is something like, even after deployment via powershell on the production environment:

```
http://app-75f4d3f46f30bc.domain.com/sites/sitecollectionname/appname/Pages/Default.aspx?SPHostUrl=***&SPLanguage=en-US&SPClientTag=0&SPProductNumber=15%2E0%2E4787%2E1000&SPAppWebUrl=***
```

Is it possible to have a clean url? Something like:

http://mysharepoint.domain.com/sites/sitecollectionname/appname/Pages/Default.aspx

The only thing I found is [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/register-sharepoint-add-ins), but it's quite confusing to me.

Comment: When I remove the -123456789abcdef from the URL, I am still able to start the app. The parameters are even passed on. What issue did you see when you removed the app ID from the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Answer:** You cannot get a 'clean' URL without the ugly AppID in the domain.

---

**Explanation:**

The structure of an App-URL looks like this: 
`<Prefix>-<AppID>.<appdomain>.<tld>`

Example: app-1234567890abcdef.sharepointapps.local

Every App you install gets a different AppID in the URL. The App itself gets called via this URL and it is a security best-practice to encrypt this traffic via SSL. As you will get as many different URLs as you install Apps, [Microsoft's guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161236.aspx) tells you to configure a wildcard-certificate and a wildcard-record in DNS for your AppDomain.